# Delete all Anaconda / Python 3.10 / Jupyter notebook data/files to start clean installation

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I don't know what happened or what I did, but last week my Jupyter notebook totally lost its connection with the kernel. It keeps saying that the there is an error with the current kernel that it displays ("Python 3 (ipykernel)"):
[image: kernel not working / stucked]

Also, it doesn't allow me to choose a new kernel, as the option to change kernel under menu "Kernel" of Notebook is empty or it's the same kernel that it's not working:
[image: Change Kernel options]

Other weird behaviour is that if I try to save the notebook file it returns an error. Clicking in the red error doesn't even open a window to see the error message:
[image: no error is displayed when clicking on the error button]

I've struggled the whole week to configure / reinstall it but nothing worked. So far I've tried:

- the solution provided in this video:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0TLwkje6co. Didn't work
- Uninstall Anaconda and reinstall Jupyter Notebook from cmd. Didn't
  work  Upgrade Python to last version (3.10). Didn't work
- install Python and Jupyter Notebook through cmd. Didn't work
- Edit the kernel.json file

```
    %HOME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

and point the argv to the folder where python.exe is installed. Didn't work

- Uninstall all the above, clean registry with CCleaner,install all again. Didn't work

So I'm tired of trying things. I just want to reinstall everything from scratch, but it seems like somehow cleaning the registry doesn't help or something still remains after uninstalling everything that keeps preventing Jupyter Notebook to get the correct configuration with the kernel.

Can you provide a way to really clean any trace of any old Python / Notebook / Anaconda instances so I can install all of them as if they where never installed in this machine?

Sorry I can`t provide any other link / error code / hint regarding the issue, but as I said the error message in Notebook doesn't display a message.

Many thanks
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found the culprit. I've installed an ip hide soft that was intefeering with kernel (though I can't understand how and why). Once I uninstalled it everything worked as expected.